# Posting json object, waiting response in String Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I've been using the volley library for consuming services with my android app. I noticed something weird,when I try to post a json object to server, I have to make a response Listener of type JSONObject. But my server returns a String, Success or failure. Is it possible to write a JsonObjectRequest which waits for a String response? this is What I have written. The service runs correctly, but the onErrorResponse is triggered after successful post due to cannot converge String to JSON

```
            JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        Toast.makeText(StartingActivity.this,response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                error.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(StartingActivity.this,"That didn't work",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(jsonRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use StringRequest instead of JsonObjectRequest. it will return response in string Like this:

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                 Log.e(TAG,response); 
                           },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            //use this to post data.
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            //use this for headers.
        }

    };

stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            return 50000;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            return 50000;
        }

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

The jsonBody your sending to server it should be in String.

```
  JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonBody.toString(),
```

I hope this will help you. Thanks!

Comment: That's not the problem, neither the question. I ask how I can change the type of response I'm getting